# What's the cheapest way to design this circuit?

Tags: pulse, poe, cost

I design a board with Power over Ethernet (PoE 802.3af/at) and the standard requires a "Maintain Power Signature" (MPS) signal, which is a 10 mA, 75 ms pulse every 325 ms (roughly 25 % D.C.). After the flyback regulator, that 10 mA becomes ~100 mA.

Many PoE Powered Device (PD) controllers do this automatically, but they are out of stock everywhere and it probably won't get better anytime soon. So I want to take care of the pulse manually.

The first, cheapest way of doing this I could think of is with a pulse from my MCU to a NPN and resistor load. It is not the most energy efficient and it uses a IO pin (I'd rather keep it available), but I already have that NPN somewhere else, so I really only add 2 1206 resistors to my BOM.

The second way I could think of is to add a current sensor, an Op Amp and a 555 timer, like below:
[image]
(V3 is the 555, B1 + R1 is the current sensor, I1 is the rest of the board's current)
Resulting in the following waveforms:
[image]

Now, most 555 timers use about 10 mA, which is a lot. And that's 3 extra parts on the BOM, plus possibly some RC components for the 555.

Is there a way to generate this pulse for cheaper without cutting corners? The goal is to make 100s or 1000s of units for industrial / commercial use.